# Search multiple sheets and return yes or no

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have four sheets in which data is recorded. I want a formula that will search all four sheets for an ID number and return yes if the number is found and no if it is not. If it doesn't find the number on sheet 1, I want it to search Sheet 2, then Sheet 3, then Sheet 4. I can get the IFERROR(IF(MATCH... formula to search sheet one, but I can't get the formula to continue searching the other three sheets. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include the full formula used to search 1 sheet.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Since we are not a formula writing service, we need you to share the formula you are currently working with so we can help you get past where you are stuck.

Comment: =IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2,Pip!$A$2:$A$1000,0), "Present", (IF(MATCH(A2,Gleave!$A$2:$A$1000,0), "Present",(IF(MATCH(A2, McLing!$A$2:$A$1000, 0),"Present", (IF(Match(A2, Perrenoud!$A$2:$A$1000, 0), "Present",))))))), "Absent")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Sheet3!A:A,0,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Sheet4!A:A,0))),"Yes","No")
```

This assumes the value you're looking for is in A2 and the column you're searching is A; modify accordingly. (I use this formula in a music playlist spreadsheet to see if a song in my master list is in my playlist.)